# Convert project from python 2 to 3

Tags: python

"""
    I'm trying to convert a script to python 3 but I get this error

```
NameError: name 'prot_file' is not defined
```

yes I have used 2to3 but need some help in the way of the script use lines of a file to create a name a new one and then create that files

I want overcome the error

NameError: name 'prot_file' is not defined and know why is happening I cannot define the prot_file, surf_file and phi_file

### Create moved input file

## Works for only 1 pqr file so far (not multiple molecules) and only 1 molecular surface.

```
  fm = open(config_file_moved, 'w')
  for line_full in file(config_file):
    line = line_full.split()
    if line[0]=='FILE':
        if line[2]=='dielectric_interface':
            prot_file = line[1]
            prot_file_moved = prot_file + name
            new_line = line[0] + '\t' + prot_file_moved + '\t' + line[2] + '\n'
            fm.write(new_line)
        if line[2]=='neumann_surface' or line[2]=='dirichlet_surface':
            surf_file = line[1]
            phi_file = line[3]
            fm.write(line_full)
    elif line[0]=='FIELD' and int(line[5])>0:
        pqr_file_aux = line[7]
        pqr_file = pqr_file_aux[:-4]
        pqr_file_moved = pqr_file + name + '.pqr'
        new_line = line[0] + '\t'
        for i in range(1,len(line)):
            if i==7:
                new_line += pqr_file_moved + '\t'
            else:
                new_line += line[i] + '\t'
        fm.write(new_line+'\n')

    else:
        fm.write(line_full)

fm.close()

print 'Protein file: ' + prot_file
print 'Sensor  file: ' + surf_file
print 'Phi     file: ' + phi_file + '\n'
```

Comment: where is `prot_file` declared? It looks from your code snippet to be in the scope of your for loop.

Comment: Looks as if the condition `line[0]=='FILE':`  **and** `line[2]=='dielectric_interface'` are never met.

Comment: how I can declare prot_file? I think that is the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are currently defining `prot_file` here:

```
for line_full in file(config_file):
    line = line_full.split()
    if line[0]=='FILE':
        if line[2]=='dielectric_interface':
            prot_file = line[1]
```

Now, in some languages, putting the declaration this many levels of indentation inwards would be a problem. Not so in python (2 or 3) - `prot_file` will now be available outside the `for` loop, and should be usable where you're using it, right?

...Unless you don't ever take that branch of `if` statements. Because this is python, the `prot_file` name only ever gets defined if that particular line is run. If you were to go the entire `for` loop without the conditions `line[0]=='FILE'` and `line[2]=='dielectric_interference'` ever being true, then `prot_file` would never be defined and inserted into the local namespace. In that case, trying to use `prot_file` later (as you are in your `print` statement) would yield the error you're seeing, because it was never actually defined.

The only real good solution to this is to just put a dummy definition (e.g. `prot_file = ""`) at some point that the code will ALWAYS execute - such as the right before the `for` loop.

It's also worth noting that you could have the same trouble with `surf_file` and `phi_file` for the same reason.

Comment: yes, the problem is that prot_file is under several identations and is not available outside of the for loop

Comment: You can define a variable in a `for` loop and use that variable outside a `for` loop ([try it online](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/Py2/SKFCITNPoSgxLz1Vw1TTiksBCHIr48sSixRsFZQqlBS0FCq4uAqKMvNKNCDimv//AwA)). Scope in python isn't based on indentation level, it's based on namespace (functions have their own namespace, as do classes; loops and conditional blocks do not have their own namespaces, as they would in languages like C or Java or Go).